# preventDefault() traps mouseleave event on touchstart

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a tricky situation where we are using jquery to prevent a link from firing on touchstart to simulate hover on a mobile device.  The problem is that use of `e.preventDefault()` not only stops the touch event from taking us to the link, but it also stops the mouseleave event from firing on another div.  I've created a pen at

http://codepen.io/jg314/pen/DjIJe/

that shows exactly what I'm talking about.  When you touch on block one the mouseover event fires.  When you then touch box two the mouseleave event fires.  However, if you touch box one, then touch box three the mouseleave event doesn't fire, which is causing problems throughout our site.

Any suggestions?  We've tried all kinds of things and can't seem to prevent the link click, while allowing the mouseleave event to fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling the `touchend` event instead of the `touchstart` event allows for the proper bubbling of events that trigger the `mouseleave` event on the other element, while preventing the link from being opened on a touch device. I've updated the example to reflect this change: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IqAEG

Comment: I wish we could use `click`, but unfortunately then the link requires two clicks on non-touch devices as well.  Since we are only trying to replicate hover on mobile, we have to use `touchstart`.  That is, at least as far as I know.

Comment: Ah I understand your use case now - what if you bound to `touchend` instead of `touchstart` so that the link is still not opened, but the proper events are still bubbled so that `mouseleave` fires: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IqAEG

Comment: That seems do the trick.  I could have sworn we tried that, but I guess not.  I'm a little new to do this, but I'm happy to mark this as the correct solution.  Let me know the best way to do that.

Comment: Glad it works! I'll update the original answer and you can mark that as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable or two that you use for the different states. E.g. a boolean called `currentlyDraggingObject` or `disableAllButtons`. Then, instead of disabling with `e.preventDefault()`, make that function check for the state variable(s) you had set and proceeds (or not) accordingly.

Comment: Can you give us an example here using the pen?  We are using a class to determine when to use `e.preventDefault()`, but that still stops the mouseleave event from firing for the other div.